# How can I wipe m.2 ssd?

Tags: ssd

Ubuntu 18.04 is messed up because I did something with the drivers (I asked in an earlier question but no answer) so now I want to have a fresh reinstall of ubuntu 18.04. I already copied my important files, and when I booted from the usb optical drive that I originally used to boot, it just made me use a "live session"

I went in my motherboards bios, there was a secure ssd erase but it said my ssd was not supported (Asrock motherboard, sabrent rocket 256 gb m.2 nvme) so how can I wipe everything through terminal? This way I can fresh install ubuntu again

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the live session there should be an option on the desktop to install. Utilize this option and it will give you the option later on to wipe your hard drive.

Comment: Thanks! I had done this before, but I realized there was a thing on the desktop saying install Ubuntu! I should have payed more attention! Thanks for the help

Comment: Anytime! Glad you were able to get it.